# Job Scheduler and WorkManager are destroyed when the app is killed

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

Trying to put video compression in background but app gets killed `WorkManager` and `JobSchedular` Destroyed

how to solve this issue?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(ConcatVideoActivity.this, ConcatVideoJobServiceRepository.class);
                    JobInfo jobInfo;
                    PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
                    bundle.putString(FIRST_IMG, doctorCredentialModel.getDoctorFrontimg().replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
                    bundle.putString(LAST_IMG, doctorCredentialModel.getDoctorBackimg().replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
                    bundle.putString(VIDEO_URL, doctorCredentialModel.getVidUrl());
                    if(doctorCredentialModel.getDoctorName()!=null){
                        bundle.putString(DR_NAME, doctorCredentialModel.getDoctorName());
                    }else{
                        bundle.putString(DR_NAME,getString(R.string.app_name));
                    }

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(12, componentName)
                                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                                .setPersisted(true)
                                .setExtras(bundle)
                                .build();
                    } else {
                        jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(12, componentName)
                                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                                .setPersisted(true)
                                .setExtras(bundle)
                                .build();
                    }
                    try {
                        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                        int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
                        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                            Log.d("JOB SECHEDULED", "Job scheduled!");

                        } else {
                            Log.d("JOB NOT SECHEDULED", "Job not scheduled");
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }




@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job started!");

    firstImg = jobParameters.getExtras().getString(FIRST_IMG);
    secondImg = jobParameters.getExtras().getString(LAST_IMG);
    videoUrl = jobParameters.getExtras().getString(VIDEO_URL);
    drName = jobParameters.getExtras().getString(DR_NAME);
    loadFFMpegBinary(jobParameters);
    isWorking = true;
    // We need 'jobParameters' so we can call 'jobFinished'
   // startConcatVideo(jobParameters); // Services do NOT run on a separate thread
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video Customization InProgress ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return isWorking;
}
```

Comment: Give us some code sample so we can help you. How you start the JobSchedule? Is there a JobService?

Comment: Yes, using jobService

Comment: What are the circumstances of app being killed? User swiping it away from recents? Aggressive system memory saving?

Comment: while swiping, i have also enable auto start option

Comment: First of all, you are setting persisted to true that means the job will be written to disk and loaded at boot. You don't need this. Remove this and inform us if it works. Or else we will continue searching for your solution

Comment: You also asking for internet. Do you need this? If not, try to build like this new ComponentName( context, componentName ) )
         .setMinimumLatency( 10 )
         .setOverrideDeadline( 1000 )
         .setExtras( bundle )
         .build() );

Comment: still not working by removing setPersisted Need internet connection because also take video from server also

Answer (score 6):

WorkManager uses JobScheduler when running on API Level 23+, for older OS releases it uses a combination of AlarmManager and BroadcastReceivers. JobScheduler on API Level 21-22 has some implementation issues on some devices and this is the reason that WorkManager starts to use JobScheduler only on Marshmallow.

So, for API Level 23+ WorkManager and JobScheduler behave in the same way. The advantage using WorkManager is that most of the features are available starting from API Level 14.

Regarding your issue, you don't specify on which device you see this issue. Have you tried to run your sample on the emulator with a stock android image to see if the issue is still present?

Another thing that may impact your background job is the 10 minutes limit that JobScheduler (and WorkManager) imposes to background work. After 10 minutes your job is stopped.

Some device manufacturers have decided to modify stock Android to force-stop the app. This is the the reason why WorkManager will stop working (as will JobScheduler, alarms, broadcast receivers, etc.). There is no way to work around this.  Some device manufacturers do this, unfortunately, so in those cases WorkManager will stop working until the next time the app is launched.

This is reported on [WorkManager's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/113676489).

Comment: "Some device manufacturers have decided to modify stock Android to force-stop the app."

This seems to be the case with my Google Pixel XL, which sucks.

Comment: The behavior you see on Google Pixel devices is the "stock Android" one. You may be experiencing delays in your app work due to Doze mode or, if the user doesn't use much your application, it will be moved in a power bucket with less priority:https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power#buckets

Comment: Is there any way the workmanager can detect when Android force-stops the app? I need to send a report to a backend server if the Android service is ceased.

Comment: WorkManager can detect if an application has been force stopped. But you still need to have the user to manually launch the application. There's no way to avoid that:
https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/utils/ForceStopRunnable.java

When an application is force stopped all the schedule Jobs/Alarms are cancelled.